# is it possible to add a command bar to the left side of a window?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I have added a command bar to the top of the window and to bottom of the screen.
But now I want to add that command bar to the left side of a screen and it should be vertical.

Is it possible to add it like that or am I on the wrong track? Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably talking about the common implementation of a `splitview` control in Windows 10 app.

> Represents a container with two views; one view for the main content and another view that is typically used for navigation commands. - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.aspx)

This control is highly customizable and there are no written rules on how to design it. You could however follow the following guides on split view and nav pane for more info on design guidelines:

- [Navigation Pane - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/nav-pane)
- [Split View - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/split-view)

The later describes better what you are looking for:

> #### CompactOverlay
>
> A narrow portion of the pane is always visible in this mode, which is just wide enough to show icons. The default closed pane width is 48px, which can be modified with `CompactPaneLength`. If the pane is opened, it will overlay the content area.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it but you can mimic a command bar by using a splitview. Set it's display mode to compact overlay and in the pane place a list view of button or whatever you need.